# Can't access homeage after login in to phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

After I logged in to phpMyAdmin, our homepage isn't available anymore and I don't know why.

Here's the error:

> Unable to establish connection to MySQL
>
> 1044 : Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'c6dsneu'

But when I log in to phpMyAdmin, everything seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like whatever program powers your home page lost the MySQL username to connect to the database server. How you fix it will depend entirely on what software you use, but generally there's a configuration file that contains this information. You should properly set your username there. What software package is it?